# $\chi^2$ test to determine whether different observations come from the same quantity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, chi-squared-test

> Three experiments are performed to measure the same quantity $T$. The
> three results are
>
> $$ \begin{cases} T_A = 990\pm 3\\ T_B = 920\pm 30\\ T_C = 950\pm 12
>  \end{cases} $$
>
> Using a $\chi^2$ test, and assuming Gaussian errors, verify the hypothesis that the three
> experiments are measuring the same quantity.

Can anyone explain how a $\chi^2$ test should be performed for this task? Normally I would have used a t-test. I know how the $\chi^2$ works to verify the goodness of a fit but I don't know how it could be used for this task. Thanks!

Comment: Although one could *apply* a $\chi^2$ test in the sense of computing a suitable statistic, *it almost surely would not follow a $\chi^2$ distribution,* which means the computed p-value would be wrong.  The reason is that the ratio $30/3$ reflecting the range of measurement errors is strong evidence that their variances differ.  The best response from a statistical perspective is to refuse to conduct a $\chi^2$ test and to offer a better procedure in its stead.

Comment: What _data_ have you summarized to get results such as $920\pm 30?$ More to the point, what does that notation mean. Is the result $951$ rare? not yet observed? unthinkable?

Comment: This is actually an exercise so I have no background for these measurements. The error is supposed Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of how relevant/correct this answer is, but it might help you towards the right direction:

If all 3 random variables are normally distributed with known mean and variance, then $\tilde T_x = \frac{\bar T_x-\mu}{\sigma_x} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for $x \in {A,B,C}$ are standard normal distributed, where $\bar T_x$ is the sample mean. Notice how the same mean $\mu$ is assumed for all values (but not $\sigma_x$), which corresponds to the 3-equation null  $H_0: \mu_A = \mu; \mu_B = \mu; \mu_C = \mu;$, i.e. are all experiments measuring the same mean? We know that the sum of $n$ squared standard normal variables is chi-squared distributed with $n$ degress of freedom, i.e. $c = (\tilde T_A^2 + \tilde T_B^2 + \tilde T_C^2) \sim \chi^2_3$. Now a right-tailed test can be performed on the test statistic $c$.

As far as the actual numbers go I would assume the values to the left of $\pm$ are the sample means $\bar T_x$ and the values to the right are the standard deviations $\sigma_x$. For $\mu$ I'm not sure, maybe the mean of all 3 sample means.

Comment: What would this "right tailed test" based on $c$ actually test?  What is your null hypothesis?

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!